# Discord.js Ping Latency Inside Embed from Slash Command

Tags: discord.js

Newbie here. I am trying to get a slash command to send an embed with the amount of time it took between the initial message and the message response time. I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createdTimestamp')` and `Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred`. I've jumped around looking at others code trying to find a way to make this work but slash command handling still doesn't make a lot of sense to me. My code block is below. I followed along with https://discordjs.guide so if you have any other suggestions with structure feel free to comment them below. Thank you!

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply("Pinging bot...").then (async (msg) =>{
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0x0000ff')
    .setTitle('Pong! :ping_pong:')
    .addField("Time taken: ", `${msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}`)
    .setThumbnail("https://78.media.tumblr.com/be43242341a7be9d50bb2ff8965abf61/tumblr_o1ximcnp1I1qf84u9o1_500.gif")
        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        })
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to fetch the reply you send, u can use [fetchReply](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) to get the interaction reply. instead of replying with "Pinging bot..." you can defer the reply and then use the createdTimestamp. A basic example of a ping command would be

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const sent = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pinging...', fetchReply: true });
        await interaction.editReply(`:ping_pong: Pong!\n:stopwatch: Uptime: ${Math.round(interaction.client.uptime / 60000)} minutes\n:sparkling_heart: Websocket heartbeat: ${interaction.client.ws.ping}ms.\n:round_pushpin: Rountrip Latency: ${sent.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms`);
    },
};
```

You can customize the response into an embed or however you like. The djs guide has a section on ping command [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-check-the-bot-s-ping)